# How can I display the result from the age (membership) calculator in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a function to calculate elapsed time from memberships, similar to the age calculator function. So, when I click the button, it shows the result but just for few seconds, like a flash. I barely see the numbers and it seems to be doing the calculation fine. It is the first time that I see something like that since I started programming. Any idea why this might be happening?

here's code:

```js
let daysM = document.getElementById("mem-date");
let monthM = document.getElementById("mem-month");
let yearM = document.getElementById("mem-year");

let timeM = document.getElementById("mem-time");

const button = document.getElementById("calc-btn");

var today = new Date();

let d = today.getDate();
let m = today.getMonth() + 1;
let y = today.getFullYear();

let maxDays = 0;
let monthNum = 1;

button.addEventListener("click", (days, month, year) => {
    days = daysM.value;
    month = monthM.value;
    year = yearM.value;

    if (daysM.value == "" || monthM.value == "" || yearM.value == "") {
        return alert("Please enter the date properly");
    } 
    
    if (m == 1) { // Jan
        maxDays = 31;
        monthNum = 1;
    } 
    else if (m == 2) { // Feb
        maxDays = 28;
        monthNum = 2;
    } 
    else if (m == 3) { // Mar
        maxDays = 31;
        monthNum = 3;
    }
    else if (m == 4) { // Apr
        maxDays = 30;
        monthNum = 4;
    }
    else if (m == 5) { // May
        maxDays = 31;
        monthNum = 5;
    }
    else if (m == 6) { // Jun
        maxDays = 30;
        monthNum = 6;
    }
    else if (m == 7) { // Jul
        maxDays = 31;
        monthNum = 7;
    }
    else if (m == 8) { // Aug
        maxDays = 31;
        monthNum = 8;
    }
    else if (m == 9) { // Sep
        maxDays = 30;
        monthNum = 9;
    }
    else if (m == 10) { // Oct
        maxDays = 31;
        monthNum = 10;
    }
    else if (m == 11) { // Nov
        maxDays = 30;
        monthNum = 11;
    }
    else { // Dec
        maxDays = 31;
        monthNum = 12;
    }

    var memYears = y - year;

    if (m <= month) {
        m = m + 12;
    }

    var memMonths = m - month;

    var memDays = (maxDays - d) + parseInt(days);

    timeM.innerHTML = `You have been a member for ${memYears} y, ${memMonths} m and ${memDays} d`;

})
```

```html
<h1 class="headings1">Memberships</h1>

<form>
    <label id="member" for="memberdate">Enter the date you became member</label>
    <input type="number" id="mem-date" class="mem-input" placeholder="date">
    <input type="number" id="mem-month" class="mem-input" placeholder="month">
    <input type="number" id="mem-year" class="mem-input" placeholder="year">

    <button id="calc-btn">Calculate</button>
</form>

<div id="timeSection">
    <p id="mem-time"></p>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a form when you click on the button it's being submitted and page is being re-rendered. So either add `onsubmit="return false;"` to prevent submission of the form or better yet just remove the form tag since it is not required at all.

```js
let daysM = document.getElementById("mem-date");
let monthM = document.getElementById("mem-month");
let yearM = document.getElementById("mem-year");

let timeM = document.getElementById("mem-time");

const button = document.getElementById("calc-btn");

var today = new Date();

let d = today.getDate();
let m = today.getMonth() + 1;
let y = today.getFullYear();

let maxDays = 0;
let monthNum = 1;

button.addEventListener("click", (days, month, year) => {
    days = daysM.value;
    month = monthM.value;
    year = yearM.value;

    if (daysM.value == "" || monthM.value == "" || yearM.value == "") {
        return alert("Please enter the date properly");
    } 
    
    if (m == 1) { // Jan
        maxDays = 31;
        monthNum = 1;
    } 
    else if (m == 2) { // Feb
        maxDays = 28;
        monthNum = 2;
    } 
    else if (m == 3) { // Mar
        maxDays = 31;
        monthNum = 3;
    }
    else if (m == 4) { // Apr
        maxDays = 30;
        monthNum = 4;
    }
    else if (m == 5) { // May
        maxDays = 31;
        monthNum = 5;
    }
    else if (m == 6) { // Jun
        maxDays = 30;
        monthNum = 6;
    }
    else if (m == 7) { // Jul
        maxDays = 31;
        monthNum = 7;
    }
    else if (m == 8) { // Aug
        maxDays = 31;
        monthNum = 8;
    }
    else if (m == 9) { // Sep
        maxDays = 30;
        monthNum = 9;
    }
    else if (m == 10) { // Oct
        maxDays = 31;
        monthNum = 10;
    }
    else if (m == 11) { // Nov
        maxDays = 30;
        monthNum = 11;
    }
    else { // Dec
        maxDays = 31;
        monthNum = 12;
    }

    var memYears = y - year;

    if (m <= month) {
        m = m + 12;
    }

    var memMonths = m - month;

    var memDays = (maxDays - d) + parseInt(days);

    timeM.innerHTML = `You have been a member for ${memYears} y, ${memMonths} m and ${memDays} d`;

})
```

```html
<h1 class="headings1">Memberships</h1>

<form onsubmit="return false;">
    <label id="member" for="memberdate">Enter the date you became member</label>
    <input type="number" id="mem-date" class="mem-input" placeholder="date">
    <input type="number" id="mem-month" class="mem-input" placeholder="month">
    <input type="number" id="mem-year" class="mem-input" placeholder="year">

    <button id="calc-btn">Calculate</button>
</form>

<div id="timeSection">
    <p id="mem-time"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome!!! Thank you very much :) it works both way, removing form tag or adding the onsubmit="return false".

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `form` get submitted and page gets refreshed which is its default behavior, you have to prevent its default behavior, You can do as

[Read docs about preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

```
button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
```

You can prevent its behavior using `event` object that is passed to the callback that you passed to `addEventListener`

```js
let daysM = document.getElementById("mem-date");
let monthM = document.getElementById("mem-month");
let yearM = document.getElementById("mem-year");

let timeM = document.getElementById("mem-time");

const button = document.getElementById("calc-btn");

var today = new Date();

let d = today.getDate();
let m = today.getMonth() + 1;
let y = today.getFullYear();

let maxDays = 0;
let monthNum = 1;

button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  days = daysM.value;
  month = monthM.value;
  year = yearM.value;

  if (daysM.value == "" || monthM.value == "" || yearM.value == "") {
    return alert("Please enter the date properly");
  }

  if (m == 1) { // Jan
    maxDays = 31;
    monthNum = 1;
  } else if (m == 2) { // Feb
    maxDays = 28;
    monthNum = 2;
  } else if (m == 3) { // Mar
    maxDays = 31;
    monthNum = 3;
  } else if (m == 4) { // Apr
    maxDays = 30;
    monthNum = 4;
  } else if (m == 5) { // May
    maxDays = 31;
    monthNum = 5;
  } else if (m == 6) { // Jun
    maxDays = 30;
    monthNum = 6;
  } else if (m == 7) { // Jul
    maxDays = 31;
    monthNum = 7;
  } else if (m == 8) { // Aug
    maxDays = 31;
    monthNum = 8;
  } else if (m == 9) { // Sep
    maxDays = 30;
    monthNum = 9;
  } else if (m == 10) { // Oct
    maxDays = 31;
    monthNum = 10;
  } else if (m == 11) { // Nov
    maxDays = 30;
    monthNum = 11;
  } else { // Dec
    maxDays = 31;
    monthNum = 12;
  }

  var memYears = y - year;

  if (m <= month) {
    m = m + 12;
  }

  var memMonths = m - month;

  var memDays = (maxDays - d) + parseInt(days);

  timeM.innerHTML = `You have been a member for ${memYears} y, ${memMonths} m and ${memDays} d`;

})
```

```html
<h1 class="headings1">Memberships</h1>

<form>
  <label id="member" for="memberdate">Enter the date you became member</label>
  <input type="number" id="mem-date" class="mem-input" placeholder="date">
  <input type="number" id="mem-month" class="mem-input" placeholder="month">
  <input type="number" id="mem-year" class="mem-input" placeholder="year">

  <button id="calc-btn">Calculate</button>
</form>

<div id="timeSection">
  <p id="mem-time"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the below line:-

```
 <button type='submit' id="calc-btn">Calculate</button>
```

and in JavaScript file try adding the event in the parameter as below :-

```
button.addEventListener("click", (days, month, year, event)
```

and add the below line in the JavaScript file:-

```
event.preventDefault();
```

I think it should work.